# NoClassDefFoundError while creating mock object in java

Tags: java, junit

I am getting the below exception while running my test class.
 The class is trying to initialize is available with full path but at runtime gives me the error. Can anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
        at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:40)
            at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:59)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:111)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:51)
            at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:100)
            at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:58)
            at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:138)
        at com.idit.contact.server.manager.XXXTests_FindContactById.additionalDataNotSpecified_ShouldCallGetFullContactVO
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
            at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:312)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
            at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:296)
            at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:284)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
            at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:209)
            at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
            at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
            at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
            at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
            at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
            at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:42)
            at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
            at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
            at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
            at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)





     My Test Class is:

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
        @PrepareForTest({XXX.class, SomeExceptionHandler.class})
        @PowerMockIgnore({"com.abc.XXX",
                "org.apache.commons.logging.*",
                "org.apache.log4j.*"})

        public class XXXTests_FindContactById {

        @Test
            public void additionalDataNotSpecified_ABC() {

                XXX cdm = PowerMockito.mock(XXX.class);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Check the class you're trying to mock is an Interface of an Abstract class.

Comment: That class extends to an abstract class

Comment: And not a final class, right?

Comment: Yes, not a final class

Answer (score -1):

NoClassDefinitionFoundError happens when the class you want to use is not available in runtime even though it was available in compile time.Please check your classpath to know .class file is exist or not.Please study this link http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I am using some custom framework for my project and while doing junit test I am getting this error.